# Debug Assertion Failed._BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID

Tags: c++

The problem is with ***deleting x***. In the example below i created a class with a `constructor` that loads a file with integer values into an `array of x` . and a friend function to output the file and those work fine but the problem is with the `deconstructor`, I got that error and tried searching for solution but with no use.

```
 class MyFile{
    private:
        int *x;
        int size;
        FILE *file;
    public:
        MyFile(char *);
        MyFile();
        ~MyFile();
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream &co, MyFile fi);

    };


    MyFile::~MyFile()
    {
        delete x;
            fclose(file);

    }
    MyFile::MyFile(char *Loc_Name)
    {
        file = fopen(Loc_Name, "r");
        int counter = 0, reader,i=0;
        if (file == NULL){ cout << "the file doesnt exists"; exit(0); }
        else
        {
            while (!feof(file))
            {
                fscanf(file, "%d", &reader);
                counter++;

            }
            size = counter;  // the size of array equals counter
            x = new int[size];
            fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET); // to return file to set otherwise it wont get inside the loop 
            while (!feof(file))
            {
                fscanf(file, "%d", &reader);
                x[i] = reader;
                i++;
            }



        }



    }
    ostream& operator<<(ostream &co, MyFile fi)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < te.size; i++)
        {
            co << "the elements = " << te.x[i] << endl;
        }
        return co;
    }
    int main()
    {
        MyFile a("d://here.txt"); 
        cout << a;
            return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Change to: `delete [] x;`

Comment: it tried it but got the same error. @Arash

Comment: Does that file exist? Is the open successful. Because if not, the `new` on `x` does not get called.  You need to use backslash in windows `D:\\here.txt`

Comment: The file does exists and everything works fine it even outputs the data but dont know why it cant deallocate x from memory.
thanks for the suggestion to use backslash.
@Arash